# Bad Request with errormessage: invalid_client

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to create my own user system and make them login with a token.

I have used this tutorial as a starting point: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

I have created a angular app.

Every time I try to login, I get a 400 error:

> Bad Request with errormessage: invalid_client.

How can I fix this error?

---

I've created my endpoint class like this:

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        try
        {
            BCContext db = new BCContext();
            UserHelper uh = new UserHelper();
            // Retrieve user
            var user = await uh.CheckLogin(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Firstname + " " + user.Lastname));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));

                context.Validated(identity);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My authService.js:

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {
var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:55520/";
var authServiceFactory = {};

var authentication = {
    isAuth: false,
    username: ""
};

var register = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return $http.post(serviceUrl + 'api/users', data).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};

var login = function (loginData) {
    var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.username + "&password=" + loginData.password;

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";
    $http.post(serviceUrl + 'api/security/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {


        localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, username : loginData.username });

        authentication.isAuth = true;
        authentication.username = loginData.username;

        $q.defer().resolve(response);
    }).error(function (err, status) {
        //alert(err);
        console.log(err);
        $q.defer().reject(err);
    });

    return $q.defer().promise;
};

var fillAuthData = function() {
    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

    if(authData) {
        authentication.isAuth = true;
        authentication.username = authData.username;
    }
}

authServiceFactory.login = login;
authServiceFactory.register = register;
authServiceFactory.fillAuthData = fillAuthData
authServiceFactory.authentication = authentication;

return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

My loginController.js:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', function ($scope, $location, authService) {
$scope.loginData = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
};

$scope.message = "";

$scope.login = function () {
    authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
        $location.path('/users');
    }),
    function (err) {
        $scope.message = err.error_description;
        console.log(err);
    }
};
}]);
```

My authInterceptor.js:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

var request = function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return config;
}

var responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }

    return $q.reject(rejection);
}

authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = request;
authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = responseError;

return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

My login.html:

```
<form class="form-login" role="form">
<h2>Login</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="loginData.username" required autofocus />
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginData.password" required />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
<div ng-hide="message == ''" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{message}}
</div>
</form>
```

This is what I send:

[image: Request]

Comment: Try to change the request-header `Content-Type` to `application/json` in your `authService.login` function.

Comment: You  are setting a default value to Content-Type header (`$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";`) but in the next line you override this (`{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }`)

Try to remove the first line and after set ``{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }``